# How to find Employee bonus basis on their sales target?

Tags: mysql

I need to find employees ids for those who met their sales targets and basis on their sales target how much bonus each one of them should get.

```
create table ta(
empid int(10),
sales int(10)
);

empid  - sales
101    - 9898
201    - 988
301    - 87988
401    - 88
501    - 202088

 create table tb(
 target int(10),
 bonus varchar(100));

Target  - Bonus
1000    - 25%
5000    - 50%
10000   - 70%
50000   - 85%
100000  - 100%
```

=================================
i have tried

```
select ta.*
from   ta
    right outer join tb on ta.sales=tb.target
where sales <= bonus;
```

And

```
select empid, sales, target, bonus
from ta 
    join tb on ta.empid=tb.bonus
where target < 100000
```

Comment: where is the same column[primary->foreign] in both table to do join ?

Comment: And what's the problem with the given queries?

Comment: *"I need to find employees ids for those who met their sales targets and basis on their sales target how much bonus each one of them should get."* Which results are expected i meant with this you should make a expected output resultset.

Answer (score 1):

First get all the targets the employee has met and then get the top target:

```
select t.empid, t.target, tb.bonus from (
  select empid, max(target) target
  from (
    select *
    from ta inner join tb
    on tb.target <= ta.sales
  ) g 
  group by empid  
) t inner join tb on tb.target = t.target
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hpMjdREnTcRHFJVwcbbtZq/0).
Results:

```
| empid | target | bonus |
| ----- | ------ | ----- |
| 101   | 5000   | 50%   |
| 301   | 50000  | 85%   |
| 501   | 100000 | 100%  |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following solution using a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT ta.empid, ta.sales, MAX(tb.target) AS target, CONCAT(MAX(REPLACE(tb.bonus, '%', '') + 0), '%') AS bonus
FROM ta LEFT JOIN tb ON tb.target <= ta.sales
GROUP BY ta.empid, ta.sales
ORDER BY ta.empid
```

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92ec15169b9d630929d06d82280a8f04)

To get all employees you can use the `LEFT JOIN`. In case you want to see only the employees with bonus you have to use a `INNER JOIN` or condition on `HAVING` like the following:

```
SELECT ta.empid, ta.sales, MAX(tb.target) AS target, CONCAT(MAX(REPLACE(tb.bonus, '%', '') + 0), '%') AS bonus
FROM ta LEFT JOIN tb ON tb.target <= ta.sales
GROUP BY ta.empid, ta.sales
HAVING MAX(tb.target) IS NOT NULL -- or just using INNER JOIN
ORDER BY ta.empid
```